# Is the following statement correct: $ LCM(X^3YZ,XZ^2)=XZ^2$

Tags: polynomials

I just wanted to clarify that the following statement is correct.
$$ LCM(X^3YZ,XZ^2)=XZ^2$$
Any helpwould be great thanks.

Comment: are $X, Y, Z$ primes? then then the LCM is $X^3YZ^2$

Comment: You'll want to collect the highest powers of each.  For example, the highest power of $Z$ is $Z^2$.

Comment: Besides correcting the Y factor, you also need to assume, e.g. that X,Y,Z are pairwise coprime.

Comment: I am trying to calculate the S-polynomials of a pair of polynomials; so just verfying that my LCM(LM(f),LM(g)) is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $LM(g)$? What are $S$-polynomials?

Comment: It looks like you computed the $\gcd$ on accident!

Comment: ^Actually, the gcd would have been $XZ$ not $XZ^2$.

Answer (score 1):

LCM would be $X^3YZ^2$  you take the highest powers of each term from both!

Answer (score 0):

If X is 1 and Y is a factor of Z, then only what you said is true.
LCM is a multiple of both numbers next to 0, so if X<sup>3</sup>YZ is a factor of XZ<sup>2</sup> only then what you said is true and what I said above is the condition for that(there'd be other condition that X<sup>2</sup> is a factor of Z<sup>2</sup>/Y, so X may not be 1)
So if all of them are integers, only if X<sup>2</sup> is a factor of Z<sup>2</sup>/Y, LCM(X<sup>3</sup>YZ, XZ<sup>2</sup>) =XZ<sup>2</sup>